# How to save state of different UIImageView present on UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I have different images on my `UIView` and I have created a subclass of `UIImageView` from where I perform operation like rotation, zoom-in,zoom-out,flip. I am able to do that successfully, but the problem is that if I have zoomed the `UIImageView` and then I perform flip operation, then the flip operation works not on zoomed image but it operates on initial image that I was having in the starting.

Does anyone has some idea regarding state saving?

Comment: then you will have to implement your own flip operation or repeat your previous custom operations after the flip again

Answer (score 1):

You can save current state of `UIView` content to `UIImage`

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
[yourImageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

That you can set this image to your image view and flip it, if you need to be able to undo actions you need to save context on every stage, but this can cause memory problems if image is relatively big.

I hope this will help you. But if this idea don't feet your needs you can try to describe it with more details.